# database: how to create the update cascade tables and query data?

Tags: mysql, database, cascade

I want to create a database have two tables. I want to create a update cascade relationship between two tables. If the SNAME was changed in EMPLOYEE, then WORKREPORT will change his SNAME too.

```
EMPLOYEE:
SNO      SNAME           SPASSWORD     SEX      BDATE           HEIGHT    BTITLE
2014      boss            12345        male      1987-06-02       180       Manager
2015      Tom             1234567      male      1987-06-05       180       Employee


WORKREPORT
   SNO       SNAME             SDATA         SCHECKLIST       SIMAGE
   2014      boss            1987-06-02      abc               afafafaf
   2015      Tom             1987-06-05      affafa            afafafaf
```

My code works very well. My problems is that : I don't know how to only query the employee's information(rather than manager) from the "WORKREPORT", suppose there are many employees. What should I do? Am I right about about the designing "WORKREPORT"?
This is my code:

```
CREATE database  if not exists cm360_cm360_1;
use cm360_cm360_1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE(SNO VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,  SNAME VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,  SPASSWORD VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,SEX VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,  BDATE DATETIME NOT NULL,  HEIGHT DEC(5,2) DEFAULT 000.00,BTitle VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY(SNO), UNIQUE KEY (SNAME))ENGINE=InnoDB ;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2014,'boss','12345','male','2014-6-10 11:00:00',160.00,'Manager');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2015,'Tom','1234567','male','2014-6-10 12:00:00',160.00,'Employee');
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORKREPORT(SNO VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,  SNAME VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,SDATA DATETIME ,  SCHECKLIST VARCHAR(150),SIMAGE VARCHAR(20),FOREIGN KEY (SNO) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (SNO) ON UPDATE CASCADE,FOREIGN KEY(SNAME) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (SNAME) ON UPDATE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB;


INSERT INTO WORKREPORT VALUES (2014,'boss',' 2014-6-10 14:38:59','abc','afdsfdfds');
INSERT INTO WORKREPORT VALUES (2015,'Tom',' 2014-6-10 15:38:59','abc','afdsfdfds');
SELECT * FROM  WORKREPORT order by SDATA ASC;

UPDATE WORKREPORT SET SCHECKLIST='elevator;floor' WHERE SNAME='hanlu2';
delete from workreport WHERE  SIMAGE='N/A' AND SNAME='enlan';
```

Comment: You are using `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. doesn't it work?

Comment: It works very well. My problems is that : I don't know how to query the employee's information from the "WORKREPORT", suppose there are many employees.

Comment: Just do a join between the tables with the Fk column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get Employee WORKREPORT information, query below should work..

```
SELECT WORKREPORT.* 
FROM WORKREPORT, EMPLOYEE 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.SNO = WORKREPORT.SNO 
AND EMPLOYEE.BTITLE = "Employee"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get all employee information, you can `JOIN` the two tables on `SNO` and/or `SNAME` since you have a FK relationship on those column and filter by the condition that `BTITLE` shouldn't be `MANAGER`

```
select e.*
from employee e
join workreport w on e.SNO = w.SNO
and e.SNAME = w.SNAME
and e.BTITLE <> 'Manager'
```